# Playing the default Beep sound

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to play the default Twilio beep sound? Based on the docs, it seems like it's only available with `<Record>` and `<Conference>`. I would want to achieve something like this:

```
<Say>Enter your answer after the beep.</Say>
<Gather action="/blah"></Gather>
/* Beep sound goes here */
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can play anything you want by using the [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) verb. So in the example above, you could do the following:

```
<Say>Enter your answer after the beep.</Say>
<Play>https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-01a.mp3</Play>
<Gather action="/blah"></Gather>
```

That way, it will say your text, and then it will play a beep sound and start processing your `<Gather>`.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: How would this look in c#